# connect 2 containers, call python container and execute script.py from golang container

Tags: python, docker, go, docker-compose, docker-network

I am using two docker containers to develop a web app. Inside my golang docker container i have my web server, after submiting a form I want to process the inputs in my Python container. My first idea is to use golang:

```
exec.Command('python3', 'script.py', 'args')
```

But I don't know how to call the Python container, like using its bash terminal instead of the golang one. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by the `bash terminal` of python ? Do you mean the command line interface that is opened when you use the `python` program from bash without argument ?

Comment: Inside a docker container you have a Linux system with its own terminal (bash). So, to execute a script inside my container I use: python3 script.py arg1 arg 2

Comment: A Docker container usually runs a single process; it usually does not have a terminal, and the image may not include `bash` or even a shell at all.  You might look into using tools like Docker Compose to start two separate containers (one each for the Go and Python applications) and making HTTP requests between them.

Answer (score 3):

by essence, the docker containers are isolated and you cannot *directly* execute code from one in another.
In the microservice philosophy, you would more preferably *expose* and API in the python container and call this API from the go container.

On the other hand, from the *host*, you can execute a `one shot command` inside your python container by using `docker exec <command>`